# Python plotly subplots with multiple columns

Tags: python, plotly, multiple-columns, plotly.graph-objects

I have a code as below, which basically uses plotly and plots multiple columns of dataframe.
The below code works fine. But I want use this graph as a subplot. Imagine having 3 rows and 2 columns and wanting to show a similar graph from this function as a subplot.

```
def custom_graph_objects(df, item, show=False):
    # Create the Plotly figure
    fig = go.Figure()


    # Add Percentage Change trace with markers and labels
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['vpl_start_week'][df['wh_item_code']==item], y=df['list_price'][df['wh_item_code']==item], mode='lines', name='list_price'))

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['vpl_start_week'][df['wh_item_code']==item], y=df['current_sell_zone1'][df['wh_item_code']==item], mode='lines', name='current_sell_zone1'))

    # Add Percentage Change From Initial trace with markers and labels
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['vpl_start_week'][df['wh_item_code']==item], y=df['percentile_difference'][df['wh_item_code']==item], mode='lines',
                            name='percentile_difference'))

    # Set the title and axis labels
    fig.update_layout(title='Item Price Analysis',
                    xaxis_title='vpl_start_date',
                    yaxis_title='price')
    fig.update_traces(mode="lines", hovertemplate=None)
    fig.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")
    if show:
        fig.show()
    return fig
```

[image]

the below is the code which I tried for subplots but it does not reflect what I needed.

```
r = 2
c = 2
sample_items = random.sample(grand_aggregate['wh_item_code'].unique().tolist(), r*c)
sub_fig = make_subplots(rows=r, cols=c)
pos = [(x+1, y+1) for x in range(r) for y in range(c)]
for i, item in enumerate(sample_items):
    sub_fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=grand_aggregate['vpl_start_week'][grand_aggregate['wh_item_code']==item], 
                                 y=grand_aggregate['list_price'][grand_aggregate['wh_item_code']==item], mode='lines', name='list_price'), 
                  row=pos[i][0], col=pos[i][1])
    sub_fig.update_traces(go.Scatter(x=grand_aggregate['vpl_start_week'][grand_aggregate['wh_item_code']==item], 
                                    y=grand_aggregate['current_sell_zone1'][grand_aggregate['wh_item_code']==item], mode='lines', name='current_sell_zone1'), 
                  row=pos[i][0], col=pos[i][1])
    sub_fig.update_traces(go.Scatter(x=grand_aggregate['vpl_start_week'][grand_aggregate['wh_item_code']==item], 
                                    y=grand_aggregate['percentile_difference'][grand_aggregate['wh_item_code']==item], mode='lines', name='percentile_difference'), 
                  row=pos[i][0], col=pos[i][1])
    
sub_fig.update_layout(height=900, width=1200, title_text="Subplots")
sub_fig.show()
```

[image]

any help on this is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A subplot in plotly creates one object with `make_subplots(rows=r, cols=c)` and sets the graph to a subplot, which is one of the matrices of the object. So there is no need for `fig=go.Figure()` in the function, and fig is required as an argument. The sample data has multiple columns, but I created a function to expand it into subplots, and then created code to complete the whole thing in a loop process.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df = px.data.stocks()

df.head()
date    GOOG    AAPL    AMZN    FB  NFLX    MSFT
0   2018-01-01  1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
1   2018-01-08  1.018172    1.011943    1.061881    0.959968    1.053526    1.015988
2   2018-01-15  1.032008    1.019771    1.053240    0.970243    1.049860    1.020524
3   2018-01-22  1.066783    0.980057    1.140676    1.016858    1.307681    1.066561
4   2018-01-29  1.008773    0.917143    1.163374    1.018357    1.273537    1.040708

r,c = 3,2
sample_tickers = df.columns.tolist()[1:]
sub_fig = make_subplots(rows=r, cols=c)
pos = [(x+1, y+1) for x in range(r) for y in range(c)]

def custom_graph(df, tick, sub_fig, pos, show=False):
    sub_fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=df['date'],
        y=df[tick],
        mode='lines'
    ), row=pos[0], col=pos[1])
    return sub_fig

for i,(tick,p) in enumerate(zip(sample_tickers,pos)):
    sub_fig = custom_graph(df, tick, sub_fig, p, show=False)

sub_fig.update_layout(height=900, width=1200, title_text='Subplots')
sub_fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response r-beginners. I came across this code which uses rows and cols to specify where the fig should go and sit. My requirement is to have graph with multiple columns. So in this case, say if we are plotting trends of GOOG, AAPL, etc,. along with the average. I need both trend and average within the same subplot.
```
sub_fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=df['date'],
        y=df[tick],
        mode='lines'
    )
sub_fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=df['date'],
        y=df[tick].mean(),
        mode='lines'
    )
```
This only shows average but not trend.

Comment: My answer is refactored as a sub-plot example using graph functions. I have used sample data as no reproducible data was presented for your data. The data part should be modified by you. Add trend lines if you need them.